Assigning Raster Values from TIFF File to Point Locations in R
I'm working on a spatial analysis project in R where I have two datasets:
Village Dataset (village_data):
    Contains latitude and longitude coordinates for each village in India.
    Includes attributes like electricity access and other demographic details.
    Stored in a GeoJSON file without geometries (empty geometries).

Raster Dataset (elec_change.tiff):
    A TIFF file representing changes in electricity access between 2019 and 2023 (satellite data).
    Pixel values range from -2 to 2, corresponding to categories indicating changes in electricity access.
        Negative values (-2, -1) may indicate a decrease in access.
        Positive values (1, 2) may indicate an improvement.
        A value of 0 could indicate no significant change.
    The raster does not align with village locations and consists of random points/locations where data was collected.

Both datasets are in the WGS 84 coordinate reference system (EPSG:4326).
I aim to assign the raster values from the TIFF file to each village based on their geographic location.
Here's the code I've been using:
library(sf)
library(terra)

# Load village data
village_data <- read.csv("village_data.csv")  # Or use st_read() if it's a GeoJSON
# Replace 'longitude' and 'latitude' with your actual column names
village_sf <- st_as_sf(village_data, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326)

# Load raster data
raster_data <- rast("elec_change.tiff")

# Check and align coordinate reference systems
village_sf <- st_transform(village_sf, crs = crs(raster_data))

# Convert village data to SpatVector
village_vect <- vect(village_sf)

# Extract raster values using nearest neighbor method
extracted_values_nn <- extract(raster_data, village_vect, method = 'simple')

# Add extracted values to village data
village_sf$Z_score_nn <- extracted_values_nn$layer

The problem with this was that the nearest neighbor method may not accurately represent the raster values at the village locations.
What is the best method to assign raster values to point locations when they don't align perfectly?

Using method="simple" is not returning a nearest neighbor, it is a direct intersecting point-in-pixel value. Whereas, using bilinear interpolates the four nearest pixels. So, yes this is the best way to assign underlying pixel values to your points. BTW, extract will take an sf class object so, no need to create a terra SpatVect object.

What does "The raster does not align with village locations and consists of random points/locations where data was collected." mean? Is the raster random points/locations? What's between those points on the raster? Or do you mean the village locations are random points? Can you show us a plot of these thiings?

You have a problem where you need to account for "fuzziness" (uncertainty) in the data. This is normally done by simply taking the mean or median of the pixels within a certain distance. However, if I understand correctly, you functionally have nominal data. This requires an assessment of frequency or percent of the categorical values. Then you could take the highest frequency value, and evaluate the fuzziness associated with other high frequency values. Here is an example of how one may approach this issue.
First lets create some example data using the meuse point data and a random raster with your nominal (-2, -1, 0, 1, 2) values.
library(sf)
library(terra)
if(require(sp, quietly = TRUE)) {
 data(meuse, package = "sp")
 villages <- st_as_sf(meuse, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 28992, agr = "constant")
}

evals <- c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2)
elec_chg <- rast(ext(villages), resolution = 30, crs="EPSG:28992")
  elec_chg[] <- sample(evals, (nrow(elec_chg) * ncol(elec_chg)), replace=TRUE)

plot(elec_chg)
  plot(st_geometry(villages), pch=20, col="red", cex=2, add=TRUE) 

Now, this code looks nasty but I will attempt to explain. We first extract raster values from buffered points, which can be done in one fell swoop, creating the "vb" data.frame. Since we extracted and area, the ID column represent the multiple pixels within each polygon and the second column the actual raster values.
We then use lapply to loop over the unique polygons/pixel values. The use of prop.table(table(x)) returns the proportions of each raster value. By declaring a factor with fixed levels, the resulting table contains all values, even if they are missing. This way everything stays symmetrical. The do.call function binds the resulting list object into a data.frame.
s = 60 # search radius
vb <- extract(elec_chg, st_buffer(villages, s))
  elec.pct <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(vb$ID), \(i) {
     prop.table(table(factor(vb[vb$ID == i,][,2], levels=evals)))
  })))
names(elec.pct) <- c("neg_two", "neg_one", "zero", "one", "two")

Now that we have a data.frame with proportions of each class, we can evaluate which class is the maximum and create a column with that class. The apply function looks across rows and which.max returns the index of the maximum value. So, the pmax vector is an index of the position of the maximum and can be applied to our original evals vector to pull the correct class (you gotta love how the ordering is retained). This can then be added back to the sf villages point object. Not only do you have the class, but associated proportion of each of the other classes present in the search radius.
pmax <- apply(elec.pct, MARGIN=1, which.max)
elec.pct <- data.frame(elec.pct, class = factor(evals[pmax]))

( villages <- cbind(villages, elec.pct) ) 
  plot(villages["class"], pch=20)

